# Jackson error when enable proguard (minify)

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I use implementation `'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'` and when i enable minify i get this errors

```
2019-06-27 20:23:11.172 28675-29539/? W/System.err: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.example.tst.a.b.b and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.172 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
2019-06-27 20:23:11.173 28675-29539/? W/System.err:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219)
```

this is what i add ProGuard rules but it doesn't fix my problem

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
 -keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
     public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
    *;
}
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add exclusion rules to prooguard for your models, or you need to add this annotation to each property of your models:

```
@JsonProperty
```

for instance

```
@JsonProperty("propertyName")
val propertyName: String
```

Basically you have to prevent proguard from mangling your property names (with the exclusion), or add the annotation so the mangling doesn't matter.